# react context not working when provider placed at certain parts of the element tree

Tags: reactjs, use-context

I'm using a react context to manage a large input form, and I want the provider to be placed just around that input form. But it throws the following error: "A context consumer was rendered with multiple children, or a child that isn't a function. A context consumer expects a single child that is a function. If you did pass a function, make sure there is no trailing or leading whitespace around it." This is my context:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const AddHeaderContext = React.createContext({
    headerType: "",
})

export const AddHeaderContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [headerType, setHeaderType] = useState("noimage")

    const headerTypeChangeHandler = (type) => {
        setHeaderType(type)
    }

    const contextValue = {
        headerType: headerType,
    }

    return (
        <AddHeaderContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
            {props.children}
        </AddHeaderContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AddHeaderContext
```

This is when there is an error:

```
import AddHeaderContextProvider from './store/AddHeaderContext'

<AddHeaderContextProvider>
    <AddHeaderSection />
</AddHeaderContextProvider>
```

But weirdly the error disappears when I move the context up into my index.js top level element and wrap everything in it.
Any idea why that could be? Also, I tap into this context usinig "useContext" hooks and not .Consumer.

Comment: You probably should include a link to a runnable example reproducing your issue e.g. jsfiddle. There is too little context to be able to judge.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:
I just needed to use curly brackets around the contextProvider since it wasn't the main export from that file:

```
import { AddHeaderContextProvider } from './store/AddHeaderContext'

<AddHeaderContextProvider>
    <AddHeaderSection />
</AddHeaderContextProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this `export default AddHeaderContext` in `AddHeaderContext.js`, so when you do `import AddHeaderContextProvider from './store/AddHeaderContext'`
you are actually getting `AddHeaderContext` (the default export), not `AddHeaderContextProvider`.

Either change your import to `import {AddHeaderContextProvider} from './store/AddHeaderContext'` or your exports as below:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

export const AddHeaderContext = React.createContext({
  headerType: "",
});

const AddHeaderContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [headerType, setHeaderType] = useState("noimage");

  const headerTypeChangeHandler = (type) => {
    setHeaderType(type);
  };

  const contextValue = {
    headerType: headerType,
  };

  return (
    <AddHeaderContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{props.children}</AddHeaderContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AddHeaderContextProvider;
```